# How to put a QED symbol in the margin?

Tags: symbols, margins

As I badly explained here [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134204/how-to-put-a-symbol-always-in-the-right-margin-even-in-twoside-mode-like-line) I wish to put my QED symbol on the same line as the last word of my paragraph, but in the margin like the package lineno does for the line number.

I tried the trick to use `\rlap` but it does not work.
I do not wish to use the environment theorems and so on.
See for yourself,

[image]

```
     %\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, draft, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[right,mathlines]{lineno}

\def\qed{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}$\heartsuit$}}

\def\qedd{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{1cm}$\heartsuit$}}

\setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\voffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\textheight}{237mm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{150mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{10mm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{40mm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\evensidemargin}
\setlength{\topmargin}{20mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{5mm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{10mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{10mm}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{0mm}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{0in}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.1}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\linenumbers[10000]

\textbf{Here the symbol goes where it should, just  next to the number line:}\\
Ksjdahf lksjadhfl lasdjhflsad fljsdhaf skjdahl lajsdhl skl lakjhfa klkajhdsfldskfhfd weoew.
\qed

\textbf{Here the qed symbol goes to the next line instead of the right margin because of the E:}\\
Ksjdahf lksjadhfl lasdjhflsad fljsdhaf skjdahl lajsdhl skl lakjhfa klkajhdsfldskfhfd weoewE.
\qed


---------------------------------------------------------------------\\
\textbf{when hspace is set to 1cm, the problem is still present:}


Ksjdahf lksjadhfl lasdjhflsad fljsdhaf skjdahl lajsdhl skl lakjhfa klkajhdsfldskfhfd weoew.
\qedd


Ksjdahf lksjadhfl lasdjhflsad fljsdhaf skjdahl lajsdhl skl lakjhfa klkajhdsfldskfhfd weoewE.
\qedd



\textbf{How to actually set the symbol in the margins, where the line numbers are ?}








\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

In your example document, `\qed` (and `\qedd`) follow a space at the end of the sentence. Although not extensively tested, try

```
\def\qed{\leavevmode\unskip\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}$\heartsuit$}}

\def\qedd{\leavevmode\unskip\hfill\rlap{\hspace{1cm}$\heartsuit$}}
```

which should recover any unwanted spaces before proceeding to fill and place the `\heartsuit`. A more LaTeX-y way would be

```
\newcommand{\qedd}{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\hfill\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{1cm}$\heartsuit$}}
```

Comment: so I tried the solution of Werner, but it does not cope well with the mathmode:
![qed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EbiyJ.png) \documentclass\[twoside, a4paper, draft, 11pt\]{article} \usepackage\[right,mathlines\]{lineno} %\def\qed{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}$\heartsuit$}} % %\def\qedd{\hfill\rlap{\hspace{1cm}$\heartsuit$}} %\def\qed{\leavevmode\unskip\hfill\rlap{\hspace{0cm}$\heartsuit$}} %\def\qedd{\leavevmode\unskip\hfill\rlap{\hspace{1cm}$\heartsuit$}} \newcommand{\qedd}{% \leavevmode\unskip\hfill\makebox\[0pt\]\[l\]{\hspace*{0cm}$\heartsuit$}} \setlength{\paperheight}{297mm} \setlength{\paperwi

Answer (score 3):

Might be an idea to use the `marginnote` package to put it into the margin